# Accessing a CollectionViewCells data when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` who's data I want to access when tapped. The data will be used in another view controller... For instance, when I tap on a friend, the next viewcontroller presented will be a page with the tapped friends data.

Here is my `didSelectItemAt IndexPath`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let vc = JoinGroupChatController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    vc.selectedIndex = indexPath

    let liveCell = LiveCell()
    vc.descriptionLabel = liveCell.descriptionLabel.text

    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In essence this is what I want to do however I need the indexPaths specific description label not the default liveCell label text.

I know I need to use the indexPath somewhere just not sure where / how.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not be getting the cell at all. You should be accessing the data from the data model used to populate the collection view. A cell is not your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
let liveCell = LiveCell()
```

with

```
let liveCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! LiveCell
```

Comment: No, this is not the correct solution. You should not be getting the cell at all. You should be accessing the data from the data model used to populate the collection view. A cell is not your data.

Comment: If you can get the data from a data source list with the indexPath specified, and it's definitely a better way.

Comment: It's the exact same code in the `cellForItemAt` method used to configure the cell. That same logic should be used here to access the same value.

Comment: @rmaddy The answer above works perfect so far and was the solution I was expecting. The next cell presented is a essentially a copy of the previously selected cell in another view controller. Maybe this is not a conventional method of doing that? Are there any significant pros/cons between the two methods?

Comment: @Stefan A cell is not your data. If you wish to access your data, then access your data from your data model, not the view which was populated with a representation of your data. Imagine your cell displays a date or a number. Your cell would contain string representations of the original dates/numbers. So trying to get the data from the cell would be a poor choice. You would get the original, actual dates/numbers from your data model.

Comment: @rmaddy That actually makes sense. I just tested out both methods and while they both work in this scenario, you're right in the sense that it's probably safest to access the data straight from the data model in case you don't have the original value stored within the cell. Thank you both.